# Hello, not sure how to do photos, but any help with water tank / well would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Tags: well, well-pump, water-tank

We have an old and not well maintained house for many years until we got it couple years ago. The original water tank and pipes that go to a well are old.

So this is what we have done so far / what happened:
Yesterday:
-More people were at our house using more water then we have before
-My father worried about the pressure did the ‘tap under pressure switch with screwdriver’ thing on the water tank, there were sparks.
-Soon after the water stops working, pressure gauge is stuck at 20 but it’s basically 0 because the gauge sucks. We keep tapping with the screwdriver throughout the process but nothing happens
-While water tank electric switch was on we went away for about an hour, when we came back the water worked perfectly fine for 20s or so, then stopped again.
-We replaced the pressure switch (a 20/40, even though the air pressure was at 28) and installed a 30/50. We rewired correctly, electricity is flowing to the pressure switch, but the water pressure gauge remains as 0 whether whatever we do. We tried the same with a new 20/40 (set air psi to 18) but no luck.
-We think well maybe ran dry, so decide to wait till evening / next day.
Next day (today):
-Everything the same, water pressure gauge at 0. We continue our googling and research, decide to buy a new water tank because ours is in terrible shape regardless if its the actual problem or not. Nothing changes. There is no to very little sediment in the piping, the current is reaching the pressure switch though. The controller in in the well, not the house, we haven't tried anything with that yet. We looked down the well to try and glean some info but couldn't see very far.

We would appreciate any advice or tips, we are happy to call the plumber if its necessary but we really need the cash for other priorites right now, bad timing.

Thank you,
A novice homeowner

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post for the default picture help. [edit] your post to add them.

Comment: Is the pump at the surface or down in the well? how many pipes come from the well? One pipe, pump n surface - shallow well pump. Two pipes, pump on surface - jet pump - either of those may need priming. one pipe, pump in well, submersible pump no need to prime.

Comment: Hopefully it is just a repair needed somewhere, but if you are at plus ~20 year old parts/pump then a replacement is more likely.

Comment: Or just a rebuild kit, depending, @crip659 - if the motor and pump housing are OK, all the other parts are usually replaceable at much less than the cost of a new pump.

Comment: @Ecnerwal there is one pipe going from water tank to well. How do I prime? Ive been watching videos about putting water in, is that what you mean?

Comment: Is there a motor attached to the surface piping, or is there no such thing? (the latter would mean you have a submersible pump, which is the most common case these days)

Comment: If the pump is submersible, it should not need any priming. If the pump is on the surface it might. Please clarify that, and read through the picture documentation so you can post some.  The pressure switch may require holding the lever partway between "On" and "Off" if it has a low-pressure cutout, until pressure builds to 15-20 PSI or so.